# To convert a data coming in 2x to 1x clock in verilog or systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am working on validation. I current face a problem of converting a data that is coming to a unit in 2x clock.

For a signal of 132 bits it travels as 66 bit bus in 2x clock.

At receiving again all the clock conversion is to be done from 2x to 1x getting back all 132 bits of the signal.

Can somebody help me on how to do this ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have a signal in the 2x clock domain indicating the state of the 1x clock?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is that you have a 132 bit dual ported register. With one port in your 1x clock domain and and the other port in your 2x clock domain. As one is read only and one write only, you can just describe it like a normal register. But migrating between different clock domains is very tricky, esp. because of metastability. Do workaround this you have to add another level(s) of flip flops (i.e. another register).

My answer is not very specific and detailed, but this due to the fact, that your question is very unspecific/broad.

Comment: as long as the 1x and 2x clocks are generated and distributed to stay in phase (I would expect them to be), you don't need to worry about metastability in this case

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2008Boston_CDC.pdf) an excellent paper on clock domain crossing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged `verilog` & `system-verilog` I assume a Verilog module to do the conversion is desired.

Assuming the input & output clocks are synchronous, here is the code (not well-tested, may need some tweaks):

```
module conv_2x_to_1x (rst, clk_in, data_in, clk_out, data_out);

parameter IN_WIDTH = 66;
input wire rst, clk_in, clk_out;
input wire [IN_WIDTH-1:0] data_in;
output reg [2*IN_WIDTH-1:0] data_out;

localparam LOWER_HALF = 0, UPPER_HALF = 1;
reg [2*IN_WIDTH-1:0] data_tmp;
reg half;

always @(posedge clk_in or posedge rst)
  if (rst) begin
    data_tmp <= {2*IN_WIDTH {1'b0}};
    half <= LOWER_HALF;
  end else if (half == LOWER_HALF) begin
    data_tmp [IN_WIDTH-1:0] <= data_in;
    half <= UPPER_HALF;
  end else begin
    data_tmp [2*IN_WIDTH-1:IN_WIDTH] <= data_in;
    half <= LOWER_HALF;
  end

always @(posedge clk_out or posedge rst)
  data_out <= rst ? {2*IN_WIDTH {1'b0}} : data_tmp;

endmodule
```

I tested this with this stimulus:

```
module test;

reg rst;
reg [1:0] clk;
reg [65:0] data_in;
wire [131:0] data_out;

conv_2x_to_1x conv_2x_to_1x (rst, clk[0], data_in, clk[1], data_out);

always #5 clk = clk + 2'b01;

initial begin
  $monitor ("%3t: %1b, %2b, %66h, %66h %66h", $time, rst, clk, data_in,
            data_out [131:66], data_out [65:0]);
  clk = 2'b00;
  #2 rst = 1'b1;
  @ (negedge clk [0]) #2 begin
    rst = 1'b0;
    data_in = 66'h2d_eadbe_efcaf_ebabe;
  end
  @ (negedge clk [0]) #2 data_in = 66'h1b_adc0f_fedea_dc0de;
  @ (negedge clk [0]) #2 data_in = 66'h3c_afeba_bedea_dbeef;
  @ (negedge clk [0]) #2 data_in = 66'h0d_eadc0_debad_c0ffe;
  #12 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

If the input & output clocks are not synchronous, I think you will need to toggle a flag signal in the input clock domain which has to be double-sync'd to the output clock-domain and passed to the output logic. When the output-side logic detects the toggle, it can read `data_out` and will have to set another flag signal which has to be double-sync'd and passed on to the input-side logic. Until the input logic sees this second flag toggle I think it should not change `data_in`.